# realm large RealmResults block UI thread when data is modified

Tags: android, realm

I've been trying to test the performance of Realm with large datasets.  It seems to perform really well inserting and with queries that result in moderate resultset sizes but as soon as there is a result set that is large it starts impacting the main thread even though the actual writes are running async.  I've written a test activity that shows the issue below.  A few notes:

1. Attendee is a model with a primary key of "name" and an indexed integer field of "age".
2. The view has a text field showing the count, a button that calls reloadData on click, and an element that is interactive (I used a slider) to see skipped frames when using it.
3. If you change the query for the list so that it's causes a smaller result set (instead of less then change to equalsTo) then the issue goes away.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
package com.test.ui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.test.R;
import com.test.model.Attendee;

import io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection;
import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmAsyncTask;
import io.realm.RealmRecyclerViewAdapter;
import io.realm.RealmResults;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RECORD_COUNT = 200000;
    private static final int TRANSACTION_SIZE = 1000;
    private RealmAsyncTask mTask = null;
    private RecyclerView mAttendeeList;
    private TextView mCountText;
    private Button mButton;
    private Handler handler;
    private Realm mRealm;
    private RealmResults<Attendee> mActualList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        mCountText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count_text);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        setCountText((int) mRealm.where(Attendee.class).count());
        mActualList = mRealm.where(Attendee.class).lessThan("age", 20).findAllAsync();

        mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.deleteAll();
                setCountText(0);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                mButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                String text = "Error deleting";
                Log.e("ANRTEST", text, error);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setCountText(int size) {
        mCountText.setText(String.format("Count: %s", size));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mActualList = null;
        if(mTask != null && !mTask.isCancelled()) {
            mTask.cancel();
            mTask = null;
        }

        if(mRealm != null && !mRealm.isClosed()) {
            mRealm.close();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void loadData(final TimerUtil t) {

        Realm.Transaction.OnError onError = new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                mTask = null;
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Finished should show now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess onSuccess = new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                mTask = null;
                int count = (int) mRealm.where(Attendee.class).count();
                if (count >= RECORD_COUNT) {
                    Log.v("ANRTEST", String.format("Finished in %s seconds", t.currentElapsed() / 1000));
                    mButton.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            loadData(t);
                        }
                    }, 300);
                }
                setCountText(count);
            }
        };

        mTask = mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                int innerStart = (int) realm.where(Attendee.class).count();
                int i = 0;
                while (i < TRANSACTION_SIZE && i + innerStart < RECORD_COUNT) {
                    Attendee attendee = new Attendee();
                    int innerValue = innerStart + i;
                    attendee.name = "name " + (innerValue + 1);

                    attendee.age = innerValue % 50;
                    realm.insert(attendee);
                    i++;
                }

                Log.v("ANRTEST", String.format("Checkpoint %s (%s seconds)", Math.min(innerStart + i, RECORD_COUNT), t.currentElapsed() / 1000));
            }
        }, onSuccess, onError);
    }



    public void reloadData(View view) {

        //Setup start of process
        mButton.setEnabled(false);


        final TimerUtil t = TimerUtil.start();


       loadData(t);


    }

    public static class TimerUtil {
        private final long mStartTime;

        public TimerUtil(long startTime) {
            mStartTime = startTime;
        }

        public static TimerUtil start() {
            return new TimerUtil(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        public long currentElapsed() {
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How large is your dataset? And which order of magnitude is your time measurements?

Comment: Realm shouldn't impact the UI thread when offloading to a background thread although if you do heavy allocations, the GC will stop the world eventually which might impact the UI thread. Have you tried re-using your `Attendee` object instead of re-creating it over and over again?

Comment: I start seeing problems at between 50k and 100k entries.  I have tried transactions between 1k and 10k at a time.  It doesn't have any issue if I remove the reference to mActualList even though I don't do anything with it.  @ChristianMelchior I will try that although when I profile it the main thread is spending >30% of it's time in io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeRefresh which doesn't sound like a garbage collection issue.

Comment: Can confirm that garbage collection was not the issue (I also didn't see it when I did a systrace either, which I would expect to see)

Comment: @geisshirt I am timing in this example but really not worried about it for purposes of this test as I don't care as much how long it takes to complete compared to how much blocking of the main thread there is.  The max I go up to is 200k, and it makes it there but not before often not before I get the ANR prompt if I'm doing any UI interaction at the same time

Comment: Interesting about the native refresh. We will investigate

Comment: We are investigating this. See this issue for more details: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3685

Comment: Great thanks @ChristianMelchior